# What are the next two numbers in the sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

What are the next two numbers in the sequence?

> 0.5 / 0.5 / 1 / 0.5 / 2 / 1.5 / 0.5 / 0.5 / 1 / 0.5 / 2.5 / 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is the same as @StevenWhite's, that is,

> 0.5 and 0.5,

but I used a somewhat different reasoning:

You get the values by assigning consecutive letters of the alphabet like so:

> ```
>  c=0.5
>  d=1
>  e=1.5
>  f=2
>  g=2.5
> ```

and then using that assignment to encode the top row of this pattern:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> 0.5 / 0.5

Reasoning:

> The first 4 numbers are the same as 7-10. The next two numbers are higher by 0.5 the second time. Usually in a sequence you look at the previous number or two to determine what is happening, but in this case you have the same sequence of 4 numbers followed by a different number. So it would have to be a very long pattern. In other words, at least the first 6 numbers would have to be given before you can start determining what the next number would be. Regardless of the reasoning behind it, it appears that those first 4 numbers repeat with two increasing numbers between them. I think we would need a longer sequence to determine if that breaks down further on.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer**

I'm answering here in hopes someone can use what I've learned to solve this thing

> The first five numbers have a pattern. Take the 1st number, divide it by the second, and it gives you the next number. ex: .5 / .5 = 1 | .5 / 1 = .5 | 1 / .5 = 2. 
> I can't seem to figure out why it breaks though.